# Sumifs and referencing text in another cell in formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wish to use the sumifs formula to sum a range of cells that is given by the values in two other cells (one for the starting cell, one for the final cell). I have gotten this so far, but keep getting errors when trying to finish it:

=SUMIFS(x:y,$H$3:$H$10000,T165,$E$3:$E$10000, S165)

I want to replace x and y with the values that are in cells W170 and X170 respectively. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry for my slowness, but I'm not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: Maybe something like `=SUMIFS(INDIRECT(W170 & ":" & X170), ...)`  would help to provide some examples of what's in those two cells though.

Comment: I think I should say that the values that are in W170 and X170 are other cells, and want the formula to reference those. Not sure if that is clear

Comment: @TimWilliams - might need to add an OFFSET function to resize the range to 9998 rows.

Comment: Thanks for your help Tim, but inputting that gives a Value error. I happened upon that syntax before, but it didn't work so I assumed I did something wrong.

Comment: In the cells W170 and X170 are other cell references, which both contain numbers, which I wanted to sum, given the other criteria. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Please provide a couple of actual examples, otherwise it's pretty difficult to say for sure what's going wrong here...

Comment: Sure. I would like the sumifs formula to operate in the ranges that are displayed by the values in cells W170 and X170. Those values are O60 (in cell W170) and O65 (in cell X170). so essentially I want to sum from O65 to O70, while also retaining the option to change the values in W170 and X170. The values in the range O65 to O70 are all real numbers.

Comment: Your  "sum" and "criteria" ranges all need to be the same dimensions.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Thanks a lot for your help :)